# I have a spread operator es6 question when setting state in REACT. The current code overwrites the array with just 1 object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, setstate

I have a spread operator es6 question when setting state in REACT. The current code overwrites the array with just 1 object, i have tried using Object.assign to no avail, perhaps incorrectly. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

```
const Component = () => {
  const dataStart = [
    {
      discountRuleName: 'name',
      primaryNumber: 5,
      primaryUOM: 'units',
      ratioDeterminant: 'per',
      secondaryNumber: 1,
      secondaryUOM: 'units',
      amount: '50%',
      startDate: 'June 10, 2020',
    },
    {
      discountRuleName: 'DistanceTime',
      primaryNumber: 5,
      primaryUOM: 'Miles',
      ratioDeterminant: 'per',
      secondaryNumber: 1,
      secondaryUOM: 'Hour',
      amount: '$100',
      startDate: 'June 10, 2020',
    },
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState(dataStart);

  return (
    <UIDatePicker
      label={'From'}
      onAccept={acceptItem => {
        setData(
          ...data, //spread array
          (data[item.row.index] = {
            ...data[item.row.index],
            startDate: acceptItem.format(),
          }),
        );
      }}
      value={1}
      forceValue
      className={'Contracts__datePicker'}
    />
  );
};

export default Component;
```

[image]

Comment: Are you intending to pass an object into `setData`? Currently you're doing `...data` which spreads `data` as the parameters of the function.

Comment: You should not be using the `setData` in the rendering, I would recommend creating a separate function and look into useCallback hooks.

Comment: I want to keep the previous state while adding startDate: 'newString', to 1 of the objects in the data array.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. I made a new function that finds element by index `item.row.index` and add a new field to it **copy**. Then I replace an original object from the **copy** of a state with the **new** object I created before.

Result is a copy of a state with a new object like previous one but with additional field.

```
const setMyData = (acceptItem) => setData(prevState => {
    const elementToEdit = {...prevState[item.row.index]};

    const newArray = [...prevState];
    newArray.splice(item.row.index, 1, elementToEdit);

    return newArray;
})

.......
onAccept={setMyData}
.......
```

Use a callback in your `setState` to use you previous state value, this is a good practice.

Comment: good idea, setMyData(acceptItem, item);// to send index
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Setting array you can't assign key like you did

```js
// Array don't have key
(data[item.row.index] = {
    ...data[item.row.index],
    startDate: acceptItem.format(),
}),
```

Do this instead
If you just want to add `startDate` to existing selected item

```js
 setData( prevData =>{
    prevData[item.row.index] = {
      ...prevData[item.row.index],
      startDate: acceptItem.format(),
    }
    return prevData
});
```

Or adding `startDate` to existing selected item and expand the array with that

```js
 setData([...data,{ ...data[item.row.index], startDate: acceptItem.format()]);
```

Comment: Thanks soo much, of course pass by reference
array[index]={...array[index], key: new}

Comment: @DarkAdvent any of them help you solve your problem?